# JavaScript split input's attribute into array and output

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/myPpeO)**

**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3ysLr1p5/)**

**The goal:**

Create dynamically refreshing output with split year-month-day from the input field.

**Description:**

*Do not pay attention to any code at CodePen above the comment at line 40;*

I got an input. Whenever the user picks a date with the initialized datepicker, the input gains `data-date` attribute with `YYYY-mm-dd` format. Ok, perfect.

I want to create an output to a div based on this `data-date` attribute.

So I wrote the following code:

```
function summaryOutput() {
    var output       = $( '#output' );
    var end          = $( '#end' );

    end.on('change', function() {
        var endString    = end.attr('data-date');
        var endSplit     = endString.split('-');
        var year         = endSplit[0];
        var month        = endSplit[1];
        var day          = endSplit[2];

        output.text(year);
    });

}
```

It is pretty straightforward.

**This function is not invoked in the codepen**

Invoke it and try to select a date and see an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

And what is more, `data-date` attribute cease to apply.

What is more confusing, it works in the console. I mean, if you select a date in the datepicker and then step by step initialize all the variables and then will, for example, see what is in the `month` variable, you'll get the result.

But it ceases to work in the real document.

So am, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a data-date attribute in your input tag.

Change the input tag to look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="end" data-date="">
```

Comment: Couldn't even believe it is so easy. Well I actually thought that an error is thrown because there is no data-date attribute on the input when it is changed. I hoped that defining variables in the event listener will help. But this is SUPER EASY.